# Facing issue with WCF: Could not find default endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, service

I created a `WCF` service in separate project name is **AaWs** then added this project in a website project as a reference . website project name is **AaNuWs**

in website project web.config file is

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="AaWs.RxtraIntroService">
        <endpoint address ="AaWs" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="AaWs.IRxIntro">
        </endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

then uploaded this website project on my web server.

then give the service reference in my new project from my website with a name space

> IntroService

```
http://mywebsite/IntroService.svc?wsdl
```

new system create a new app.config file for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRxIntro" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://mywebsite/IntroService.svc/RecoverInfoTechAaWs"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRxIntro"
                contract="IntroService.IRxIntro" name="BasicHttpBinding_IRxIntro" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

but now when i trying to access this service i am getting a error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract 'IntroService.IRxIntro' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to confirm that the app.config is in the root folder with your executable.  Then confirm that the app.config has the proper value for:

```
<client>
 <endpoint ... contract=""
```

From the information you provided, the address information does not look correct.  Your service has an overall address of "http://localhost:8080/AaWs" but your service reference (wsdl url) shows "http://mywebsite/IntroService.svc?wsdl".  You surely want to make sure that you are pointing to the correct service when generating the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove name="BasicHttpBinding_IRxIntro" attribute from endpoint configuration of app.config.